# .NET C# WMI Decoupled provider cannot access files

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wmi

I am writing a small decoupled WMI provider using benefits of .NET `System Management Instrumentation`

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;

[assembly: WmiConfiguration(@"root\CIMV2", HostingModel = ManagementHostingModel.Decoupled)]
namespace MyWMIProvider
{ 
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class WmiInstaller : DefaultManagementInstaller { }

    [ManagementEntity(Singleton = true)]
    [ManagementQualifier("Description", Value = "Small description")]
    public class MyWMIClass
    {
        [ManagementBind]
        public MyWMIClass()
        { 
        }

        [ManagementTask]
        [ManagementQualifier("Description", Value = "Echoes the request.")]
        public string Echo(string input)
        {
            return "Echo: " + input;
        }

        [ManagementTask]
        [ManagementQualifier("Description", Value = "Reads text file")]
        public string ReadFile()
        {
            try
            {
                var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("readme.txt");
                return "ReadFile: " + fileContent;
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            InstrumentationManager.RegisterType(typeof(MyWMIClass));
            Console.ReadLine();
            InstrumentationManager.UnregisterType(typeof(MyWMIClass));
        }
    }
}
```

It is getting built as `Console Application` and executed inside **Administrator command prompt** using:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe" MyWMIProvider.exe
MyWMIProvider.exe
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe" /u MyWMIProvider.exe
```

The Echo method works as expected, unfortunately when running `ReadFile` I am getting an Exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)
   at MyWMIProvider.MyWMIClass.ReadFile()
```

The same issue appears when I try to use other "smarter" features as log4net.

Is there a way to resolve this issue with the current decoupled approach?